# Selenium Java: How to click on button in the table

Tags: java, selenium

[image: How to click the button]
Hello, how can i click on the Button ?
And how can i click on the button in the next row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("THE CSS SELECTOR HERE']")).click();

Comment: thanks man. i have found the problem. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated....this was missing.